# Making chocolate covered strawberries without parchment paper

Tags: chocolate

What can I use to set the strawberries on to cool if I don't have parchment paper or a cooling rack?

Comment: Cling film/saran wrap, tinfoil/aluminum foil... any sort of layer will work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are glazing only a few strawberries you can pick up the strawberries with a (wooden) skewer (toothpicks might be too short) and then poke the other end into styrofoam, a sponge or anything similar or put these into a tall and heavy glass.

[image]
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CodazziChocoBanana1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Just put a dinner plate in the fridge, then set the strawbs on that... Make sure the strawberries are drained off well after you dip 'em, and then the chill of the plate will set the chocolate.

If you have stone countertops you could set them straight on to them as well...

Comment: I'd be strictly against a chilled plate, see [this answer](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21142/4638) as an explanation.

Comment: But the cool plate would only be "disfiguring" the underside of the strawberry - the cool plate would just help to avoid sticking. I'd go with the other alternatives, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Wax paper or aluminum foil should substitute well for parchment in this case.

Comment: Aluminum foil is a terrible idea with chocolate, in my personal experience. It sticks something terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Chill them for a few minutes in the freezer. Take them out and put the plate over a boiling pot of water for a few minutes and they should wiggle off. Worked perfectly!!!