# Problem making homemade bounty bars

Tags: coconut, melting-chocolate, tempering

I tried making homemade bounty bars twice but there is a problem I can't seem to get the solution to this problem right. What I do is as follows:

I first mix a can of sweetened condensed milk with some coconut powder until a thick batter is formed. Then I put it in a mold and in the freezer (or in the fridge for a longer time). Cut into small bars, and finally covered with melted chocolate (tempered).

The problem is, as I try to coat the coconut bars with chocolate, they lose their shape and some of the coconuts pours in the chocolate and everything gets messy. I don't know how it must be done so that I can easily cover them with chocolate so that they keep their shape perfectly.

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you coating them? Could you describe the process in detail, please?

Comment: Are they still frozen when you coat them?

Comment: I guess they are @RossRidge, since I try to do the process AFAP!

Comment: I dip the bars into melted chocolates and roll, using a fork @Stephie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment:

> I dip the bars into melted chocolates and **roll**, using a fork.

If you want to coat something in chocolate, you typically need much more chocolate than you expect. The height of the chocolate should be high enough to submerge the praline or bar without rolling, otherwise you start to loose material - as you noticed. Simply dip, lift out (let excess chocolate drip off) and place on a rack or on parchment to harden. [Do not put the bars in the refrigerator](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/how-to-prevent-sweating-chocolate-covered-strawberries/21142%2321142) while the chocolate is still soft.

Another approach would be to emulate the industrial process of pouring the chocolate over the bars (on racks, parchment under the racks), but the same rule of preparing more chocolate than absolutely neccessary applies. Catch the drips and re-use, if possible.

Are you satisfied with the filling, or could you tweak it a bit to make it more stable? This might also be a way to make handling the bars easier. And if nothing helps, coat twice - once to somehow cover the bars and to contain all coconut crumbs (like a crumb coating in cake decorating), once to get a nice, even cover.