# Chocolate: condensation issues

Tags: chocolate

I made chocolates in a mold but when I take it out of the refrigerator it starts melting and water accumulates on surface.

My process:
I melted the chocolate and poured it into the mold and then kept it in the refrigerator.
But when taken out afterwards it melts at 25°C also and condensation forms on the surface.

*Is there a way to keep the surface dry at 25°C?*

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you explain a bit more *what you did exactly*? The more details, the better the answers... Again, welcome!

Comment: I melted the chocolate and poured in to the mold and then kept in the refrigerator when tken back after it gets melted at 25 deg also and moisture accumulates on surfaces is ther a way to maintain the surface dry up to a temp 25 Deg

Comment: ah nice, that's what I assumed. I was typing an answer while you added that.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/21137/8305

Answer (score 1):

There is very little information to go on, but the most likely answer from your description is condensation. Assuming that you kept it in the fridge overnight, then took it out and removed it from the mold, the chocolate will start "sweating" immediately.

If that's your problem: don't keep chocolate in the fridge. The proper temperature for chocolate hardening is 20 Celsius, try to keep at it as much as possible. If you are too much above, the chocolate can bloom, if you are below, it can condense. If you are not a perfectionist chocolatier, several degrees celsius difference in either direction will still produce a good enough result, but a fridge is always bad.